# Adding color scheme to Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to add [this](https://github.com/sjl/badwolf/) color scheme to Vim any suggestions on how I could accomplish that ?

Comment: Checkout that: http://ajayfromiiit.wordpress.com/2006/06/24/installing-color-schemes-for-vim-editor/

Answer (score 9):

1. Copy `colors/badwolf.vim` to `~/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim`; create directories if needed. Alternatively, `git clone` into `~/.vim/bundles/` and use the *Pathogen* package manager, or specify the repository with the *Vundle* package manager, etc.
2. In your `~/.vimrc`, put / replace any existing `:colorscheme` command with:

```
colorscheme badwolf
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use plugin managers like:

- https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim
- https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug
  or others like pathogen

Answer (score 0):

`cp -r [PATH]/badwolf.vim ~/.vim/colors`

`:colorscheme bad[TAB]`

If you want to use it everytime you open vim add the above command to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything that isn't already in mine.